# Hosting a C# Remoting Application

Tags: c#

i have created an Chat Application in C# using TCPChannel and Remoting Service. My Application have 3 parts one is remoteobject, second is RemoteServer and third one is ClientSide. Everything is Working fine in my pc, mean if i run server application and client application in same server its works very good, because localhost. but when i try to host my server application in my VPS and client application in my pc then i can not connect with my server application. how can i specifies an Static IP to my Server Application so i can access my app from anywhere. please help

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out your firewall settings. You will need to open a port to allow outside traffic to access the particular port on your machine.

Comment: my server side firewall is open for my selected port and protocol. i need to add a static IP to **.Net Remoting Service Object**.

Answer (score 0):

this constructor is using a fixed port: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdb9dcxt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: no, we can change the port according to our needs :) and i already changed to my free port and working fine in my own localhost pc . i need to know about how i can give my app an static ip not a localhost